# c# additional dependencies - opencvsharp

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, dependencies

I have build a c# class library "verification.dll" using OpenCVSharp.
This references OpenCvSharp.dll in Solutiondir/Dependencies/ and has copylocal = true.

The Folder "Dependencies" has 4 files OpenCvSharp.dll, opencv_core230.dll, opencv_imgproc230.dll, tbb.dll, because OpenCvSharp requires these.

Now I have made a console program "ConsoleTest" to test the functionality of the class library, and this is where the problems begin.
I have to manually place the 3 files: opencv_core230.dll, opencv_imgproc230.dll, tbb.dl in Solutiondir/ConsoleTest/bin/x86/Release/.

I don't want to do this. I want it to be possible to just reference verification.dll from the ConsoleTest, and then it just works.

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply dragged the DLL's from the folder to the project. Not as references, but as files. Set Build action: None, Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference these three dlls too, or reference the project source instead of a dll. Other options is to place these three dlls in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple if options:

- Add console test program to the solution of your projects and add referencies of the *projects* to console project. In this way any time you build a project you het latest dependencies.
- or, use your console prject's `prebuild events` to copy the necesary binaries in location you need.

Hope this helps.